# Django ading custom instance in self.request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I don't know how to extend `self.request`.

In Django rest framework or Django view, we can access many things with `self.request` like if we want to get authenticated user, then we write `self.request.user`.

I am trying to extend this to get `self.request.mycustominstance` Can anyone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These processes almost happen in the [**Django Middleware**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/) section. In your case, write your own middleware and wire-up properly in the project. To extend the ***`request`*** object, you have to do something in your [**`process_view()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#process-view) method